Different Metric Tensor on Unit-Sphere
With the standard parametrization of the unit-sphere, i.e., 
$\begin{align*}
\sigma_1:[0,2\pi]\times[0,\pi]&\longrightarrow S^2\\
\begin{bmatrix}
u\\v
\end{bmatrix}&\longmapsto\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(u)\sin(v)\\
\sin(u)\sin(v)\\
\cos(v)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}$

the metric tensor is 
$g_1=\begin{bmatrix}
\sin^2(v) & 0\\0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$. 
With an alternate parametrization, namely
$\begin{align*}
\sigma_2:[-\pi/2,\pi/2]^2&\longrightarrow S^2\\
\begin{bmatrix}
u\\v
\end{bmatrix}&\longmapsto\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\frac{2\tan(u)}{1+\tan^2(u)+\tan^2(v)}\\\\
\displaystyle\frac{2\tan(v)}{1+\tan^2(u)+\tan^2(v)}\\\\
\displaystyle\frac{-1+\tan^2(u)+\tan^2(v)}{1+\tan^2(u)+\tan^2(v)}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}$

the metric tensor is 
$g_2=\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\frac{4\sec^4(u)}{(\sec^2(v)+\tan^2(u))^2} & 0\\
0 & \displaystyle\frac{4\sec^4(v)}{(\sec^2(v)+\tan^2(u))^2}
\end{bmatrix}$.
When I calculate the arc-length of the great-circle with $y$-coordinate equal to $0$, I get $2\pi$, as expected, using both tensors (and the corresponding parametrization of the great-circle, i.e., letting $u=0$ and $t\in[0,2\pi]$ for $\sigma_1$ and letting $u\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and $v=0$ for $\sigma_2$). How can I find a different metric tensor on $S^2$ such that I get a different length for this great-circle? Or will any metric tensor on $S^2$ always give me $2\pi$? Also, how could the calculation of the great-circle go wrong if I didn't have access to the metric tensor? That is, is there a naive way of calculating the arc-length such that the different parameterizations yield different arc-lengths?

Your metrics both come from (pulling back the Euclidean space metric by) parametrizations of the unit sphere. To get a different metric you'd need to parametrize some non-spherical surface homeomorphic to a sphere. :)

Or just multiply his original metric by a positive constant different from 1.

@AndrewD.Hwang I have a parametrization for https://i.sstatic.net/CNI6Kjrk.png . If I find the metric tensor for this shape, since it's homeomorphic to $S^2$, that metric tensor will also be a metric tensor on $S^2$?

In a word, yes

@Ama yes, the object inthe picture also is an embedding of S² into R³. Different embeddings will produce different metric tensors on S².
